# PowerShell Select-String regular expression to locate two strings on the same line

Tags: regex, string, powershell

How do I use Select-String cmdlet to search a text file for a string which starts with a specific string, then contains random text and has another specific string towards the end of the line? I'm only interested in matches across a **single line** in the text file, not across the entire file.

For example I am searching to match both 'Set-QADUser' and 'WhatIf' on the same line in the file. And my example file contains the following line:

**Set-QADUser -Identity $($c.ObjectGUID) -ObjectAttributes @{extensionattribute7=$ekdvalue} -WhatIf | Out-Null**

How do I use Select-String along with a Regular Expression to locate the pattern in question? I tried using the following and it does work but it also matches other instances of either 'Set-QADUser' or 'WhatIf' found elsewhere in the text file and I only want to match instances when both search strings are found on the same line.

```
Select-String -path "test.ps1" -Pattern "Set-QADUser.*WhatIf" | Select Matches,LineNumber
```

To make this more complicated I actually want to perform this search from within the script file that is being searched. Effectively this is used to warn the user that the script being run is currently set to 'WhatIf' mode for testing. But of course the regEx matches the text from the actual Select-String cmd within the script when it's run - so it finds multiple matches and I can't figure out a very good way to overcome that issue. So far this is what I've got:

```
#Warn user about 'WhatIf' if detected
$line=Select-String -path $myinvocation.mycommand.name -Pattern "Set-QADUser.*WhatIf" | Select Matches,LineNumber
If ($line.Count -gt 1)
{
    Write-Host "******* Warning ******"
    Write-Host "Script is currently in 'WhatIf' mode; to make changes please remove '-WhatIf' parameter at line no. $($line[1].LineNumber)"
}
```

I'm sure there must be a better way to do this. Hope somebody can help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you use the -Quiet switch on Select-String it will just return a boolean True/False, depending on whether it found a match or not.

```
-Quiet <SwitchParameter>
        Returns a Boolean value (true or false), instead of a MatchInfo object. The value is "true" if the pattern is found; otherwise, the value is "false".

        Required?                    false
        Position?                    named
        Default value                Returns matches
        Accept pipeline input?       false
        Accept wildcard characters?  false
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but your suggestions doesn't really address the issue. Using -Quiet does give you a boolean true/false which is great but not what I was trying to achieve. The issue is specifying a RegEx that matches the two target strings on the same line in the target file rather than anywhere within the file.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I misread the question.  And now I don't really understand it at all.  Select-String always applies the match pattern one line at a time, and you couldn't make it match across multiple lines in a file if you wanted to.

Comment: Hi. You are completely correct. It is matching one line at a time. I was getting totally confused because the script was matching both the actual line I was searching for and the line in the script that was using Select-String to search for the matching pattern. So I guess what I am looking for is a better RegEx pattern that will only match the actual search pattern (per my original question) and not match the line with the Select-String and RegEx pattern, if that makes sense. My current approach does work but it's a bit clunky.